# Can't save or select the values to/from SQLITE

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Update: I ve solved the old problem and found a new one. It says my cursor is on row 0 and col -1 and my program crashes because of that.

I am writing a messaging application and I use SQLite store the messages but when I try to select them I always get an empty set. Here is the related class and methods.

```
    public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME="messages.db";
        public static final String TABLE_MESSAGES="messages";
        public static final String COLUMN_MESSAGE="message";
        public static final String COLUMN_JID="jid";
        public static final String COLUMN_ID="_id";



        public DBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory,DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
            String query="CREATE TABLE " +  TABLE_MESSAGES + "("+ COLUMN_ID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+ COLUMN_JID+ " TEXT, "+ COLUMN_MESSAGE +" TEXT " +" );";
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TABLE_MESSAGES);
            onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
        }

        public void addnewMessage(Messages message){
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COLUMN_JID,message.get_jid());
            values.put(COLUMN_MESSAGE,message.get_message());
            SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
            db.insert(TABLE_MESSAGES,null,values);
            db.close();
        }
        public String displayMessage(){
            SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
            String returnthis="";
            String query="SELECT *  FROM "+ TABLE_MESSAGES + " WHERE 1" ;
            Cursor c=db.rawQuery(query,null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            while(!c.isAfterLast()){
                if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("message"))!=null){
                    returnthis+=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("message"));
                    returnthis+="\n";
                }
            }
            db.close();
            return returnthis;
        }

}
```

When I send a message I use the addNewMessage(Message message) method to record the Message's string contents to my database. Here is the constructor for message.

```
public Messages(String jid, String message){
      this._message=message;
      this._jid=jid;
  }
```

I am pretty sure I have valid jid and message values before adding them to db(They are not null, I tested). When I try to display it with displayMessage method I think all I get is null (the program doesnt crash but does not give me a string value)

Comment: Try removing `+ " WHERE 1"`, which is not only **completely useless**, but also **potentially dangerous**.

Answer (score 0):

May be your insert is not successful. When you do db.insert() it will return a long value of the row. If the value is > 0 then data is inserted successfully and if it returns -1 it's not inserted. Please check the return value. Below is the sample

```
long result =db.insert(TABLE_MESSAGES,null,values);
```

Comment: It adds correctly. The problem seems to be in cursor I get something like you cannot read row 0 col -1

Comment: Can you tell me why do you have WHERE 1 in your query?